# Showing and hiding items in Windows 8 application

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I'm writing my first Windows 8 application, but I'm stuck already.

What I want to do is display an html/winjs element, depending on which index is clicked in a listview.
The current code I've written works to some extent. It will display the first element (albumListView), but after that no other items will show. I've read through the WinJS docs, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

What am I doing wrong? And is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Here's the code I've written:

My html:

```
<div id="albumListView" class="hidden" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{itemTemplate:select('#albumTemplate'), layout:{type:WinJS.UI.GridLayout}, selectionMode:'none'}"></div>
<div id="songsListView" class="hidden" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{itemTemplate:select('#songsTemplate'), layout:{type:WinJS.UI.ListLayout}}"></div>
```

My CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

My JS:

```
function hidePanelViewItems() { //hide all panel items

    var items = [albumListView, songsListView];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        WinJS.Utilities.addClass(items[i], "hidden");
    }

    return true;
}

function showItem(item) { //show a single item in the panel
    hidePanelViewItems();
    WinJS.Utilities.toggleClass(item, "hidden");

    return true;
}

args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function () {
    //hide all panel listviews
    hidePanelViewItems();
    //show the album view as a default
    showItem(albumListView);

    //deal with menu item clicks
    menuListView.addEventListener("iteminvoked", function (eventInfo) {
        switch (eventInfo.detail.itemIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                showItem(albumListView);
                break;
            case 1:
                showItem(songsListView);
                break;
        }
    });
}))
```

Thanks in advance for any replies :)

Comment: Have you tried using the `DOM Inspector` to see whether the CSS is properly applied to the "second" `ListView`?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into something similar. If you set a listview's style to display:none, you need to call forceLayout() to make it visible again. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758352.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Solved! After hours of messing around with this code, I have now discovered that it was fine all along! The problem was that data wasn't actually binding to my listviews, as they were hidden!

Comment: Don't forget to use fadeIn/fadeout animations ;P